# Proof involving angle bisector in an arbitrary triangle

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, triangles

[image]

In the above figure, AD is a bisector angle A (angle BAC). How do I prove in a triangle ABC of any dimensions that,

2. $AB > BD$
3. $AC > CD$

Is it also possible to prove that,

1. $AB > AD$
2. $AC > AD$

Comment: For this proof, I don't think AD needs to be a bisector, does it?

Comment: Well, it needs to be something --- just knowing $D$ is between $B$ and $C$ isn't enough to conclude $AB$ is longer than $AD$.

Comment: If ABD is a right angle then AB<AD, even with the bisector assumption. Are you assuming that the angle at D is a right angle, i.e. angle ADC is 90?

Comment: @coffeemath, If ABD is a right angled triangle, right angled at D, then AB would be the hypotenuse, and hypotenuse is obviously the longest side. But here, I am not sure if ADB is right angle.

Comment: Note that here nothing implies that AD is perpendicular to BC.

Comment: Each of the four statements can be true or false depending only upon $\angle ADC$.  For a conclusive answer, you should either ask "for each statement, what conditions allow the statement to be true?" or find out what $\angle ADC$ is and post that with the question.

Comment: @TabrezAhmed If you don't have any extra assumption then it is still possible for a right angle at B, which then makes AD the hypotenuse. I suggest re-cunsulting whereever you got the problem to see if any other assumptions are made, or maybe if the question is "which if any of the following are necessarily true".

Comment: @abiessu, two of the statements were from my side, I have removed them.

Comment: If all you have is that $AD$ is a bisector of $\angle BAC$, then you have no basis for the truth of any of the statements in your question.  For example, consider $\angle ABC=150^\circ$ (where $16^\circ \le \angle BAC\lt 30^\circ$), in which case both $AB \lt BD$ and $AB \lt AD$.  This is a more extreme example similar to @coffeemath's above.

Answer (score 4):

I think the first two can be proven.
Let $BC=a, AC=b, AB=c$

Now, using angle bisector theorem,$$\frac{CD}{BD}=\frac{b}{c}$$
$$BD=\frac{c}{b+c}.a$$$$CD=\frac{b}{b+c}.a$$
But $b+c>a$
$$\implies BD<c$$$$\implies CD<b$$

However as mentioned the comments, the next two parts do not always hold.